# Geting an error when using id object

Tags: iphone, objective-c, arrays, cocoa-touch, object

I'm trying to use this but getting a generic error at the lines following each if statement.

```
id genericObject = nil;
if ([searchType isEqualToString:@"1"]) {
     genericObject = MyObject1;
    }  else if ([searchType isEqualToString:@"2"]) {
     genericObject = MyObject2;
    }
self.array = [genericObject objectsFromServerDictionaries:aResultsArray];
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand what you're trying to do, try this:

```
Class genericObject = nil;
if ([searchType isEqualToString:@"1"]) {
     genericObject = [MyObject1 class];
    }  else if ([searchType isEqualToString:@"2"]) {
     genericObject = [MyObject2 class];
    }
self.array = [genericObject objectsFromServerDictionaries:aResultsArray];
```